# Problem with Latex Packages Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, latex

I'm writing a latex document in TeXworks and I'm having some problems with a couple of packages I'm using in my file, `amsrefs.sty` and `pcatcode.sty`. For some reason TeXworks decided it didn't like those guys and stopped compiling.

I tried updating `texlive-latex-base` and that didn't work. I then entered

```
apt-file -x search '/pcatcode$'
```

to find the directory the package lives in and I got

```
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsrefs/pcatcode.sty.
```

I tried cding into this directory, but I was told this directory doesn't exist. I did the same thing for amsrefs.sty and got the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files amsrefs.sty and pcatcode.sty are not included in the package texlive-latex-base so that is probably why you are told that the directory does not exist.

The files you are looking for is found in another TeX Live package, namely [texlive-bibtex-extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texlive-bibtex-extra). Install it and your document should compile. To install it do e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
```